# I can't manage different buttons with different names

Tags: php, html, button, dynamic

here is my code:

```
<?php 
   ob_start();
   session_start();
   require 'connection.php';
   require 'core.inc.php';
?>

<?php
     $take_thread_pid_query = @mysql_query(" select pid from threads ");
     $row_take_thread_pid = mysql_fetch_array($take_thread_pid_query);
     $pid = $row_take_thread_pid['pid'];

     while($row_take_thread_pid = @mysql_fetch_array($take_thread_pid_query))
     {
 ?>
  <form action="kill_threads.php" method="POST" >
  <label> <?php echo "<br/><br/>thread".$row_take_thread_pid['pid']; ?><input type="submit" value = " <?php echo $row_take_thread_pid['pid'];?> " name = " <?php echo 

  $row_take_thread_pid['pid'];  ?> " /> </label> 
  <?php }?>
  </form>

  <?php
     $t = "4756";//[4756 is on of the pids in my thread table].this is for testing but doesnt works,it cant find any button with this name.

     if ( isset($_POST[$t] ) ) echo "im a killed thread..";

   ?>
```

The big problem is that im trying to give different names to each button i create,but it seems this is not working because when im trying to see if a  button isset['???']

What i have to do...?

For example

thread 1  [button 1]

thread 2  [button 2]

thread 3 [button 3 ]

So if now i click button 1 i want thread1 row deleted from database.

phpmyadmin works like this.

Im so complicated..please help,thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is:

```
value = " <?php echo $row_take_thread_pid['pid'];?> " 
name = " <?php echo $row_take_thread_pid['pid'];  ?> "
```

You are placing spaces before and after the php text so you either have to remove the spaces or code for them

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem,the spaces,its working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use another hidden input element within the form instead of doing it with submit form, in this way you can kill all the threads with one if block by passing thread id to it.

```
  while($row_take_thread_pid = @mysql_fetch_array($take_thread_pid_query))

    {

    ?>

    <form action="kill_threads.php" method="POST" >

    <label> <?php echo "<br/><br/>thread".$row_take_thread_pid['pid']; ?>

<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $row_take_thread_pid['pid'];?>" />
<input type="submit" value = "Delete" name = "delete_thread" /> </label> <?php }?>

    </form>

    <?php

    $t = "4756";//[4756 is on of the pids in my thread table].this is for testing but doesnt works,it cant find any button with this name.

    if ( isset($_POST[$t] ) ) echo "im a killed thread..";

    ?>
```

Another problem you may come across is using multiple forms without name and id. So add a dynamic number in the form tag like like this

```
<form name="<?php echo $i; ?>" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" action="kill_threads.php" method="POST" >
```

Here $i is counter variable or you can use $row_take_thread_pid['pid'] for this purpose.